# how to do setTimeout on Yup.test?

Tags: javascript, yup

i am trying to validate an address:

```
  line1: Yup.string()
    .test(
      "Address Line 1 Validation Test",
      "Please enter valid Line 1 address",
      async (line1: string) => {
        let delayTimer = null;
        let isValid = false;
        const doSearch = () => {
          clearTimeout(delayTimer);
          delayTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get<{ status: string }>(
              "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:USA",
              {
                params: {
                  address: line1,
                  key: GEOCODE_API_KEY,
                },
              }
            );
            console.log("line1: ", line1);
            console.log("data: ", data);
            isValid = data.status === "OK" ? true : false;
          }, 1000); // Will do the ajax stuff after 1000 ms, or 1 s
        };
        doSearch();
        return isValid;
      }
    )
    .required("Line 1 is required"),
```

i want to integrate delay search like this so i don't flood my api everytime user type like this: [AJAX: Delay for search on typing in form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849221/ajax-delay-for-search-on-typing-in-form-field)

but it's doing api request everytime user type. how do i implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually never clearing the timeout.

Each time your handler runs, new `delayTimer`, `isValid` and `doSearch` variables are created and initialized. Those variables have to be placed in an outer scope. Something like this:

```js
let delayTimer = null;
let isValid = false;

Yup.string()
    .test(
        'Address Line 1 Validation Test',
        'Please enter valid Line 1 address',
        async (line1: string) => {
            clearTimeout(delayTimer);
            
            delayTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
                const {data} =
                    (await axios.get) <
                    {status: string} >
                    ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:USA',
                    {
                        params: {
                            address: line1,
                            key: GEOCODE_API_KEY
                        }
                    });
                console.log('line1: ', line1);
                console.log('data: ', data);
                isValid = data.status === 'OK';
            }, 1000); // Will do the ajax stuff after 1000 ms, or 1 s
            
            return isValid;
        }
    )
    .required('Line 1 is required');
```

Now, even if that fixes your initial problem, there is another issue to address. Your function will always return a promise with the wrong value of `isValid`.

What you have to do depends on what you want, but I'll give you the following insight:

```js
let delayTimer = null;
let isValid = false;
let resolveRef = null;

Yup.string()
    .test(
        'Address Line 1 Validation Test',
        'Please enter valid Line 1 address',
        async (line1: string) => {
            clearTimeout(delayTimer);

            if (resolveRef) {
                resolveRef(isValid);
                resolveRef = null;
            }

            return await new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolveRef = resolve;
                delayTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
                    const {data} =
                    (await axios.get) <
                    {status: string} >
                    ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:USA',
                        {
                            params: {
                                address: line1,
                                key: GEOCODE_API_KEY
                            }
                        });

                    isValid = data.status === 'OK';

                    resolve(isValid);
                    resolveRef = null;
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    )
    .required('Line 1 is required');
```

Hope it works. Please let me know.