# I want to input degree in html form with element “input “ number data type and control it with JavaScript function if it <73 then alert box

Tags: javascript, html, forms

HTML code

```
<input id="Degree" name="degree" type="number">
```

JavaScript code

```
function jsdegree(){
var deg = document.getElementById('Degree').value;
if (deg <73 ) {
  alert(" your degree is less than required ");
  }
}
```

But nothing is happening and I did’t Won’t it in submit button , I want it if I write the degree he immediately appears alert box , help me plz :(

Comment: You may use `oninput` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

Answer (score 0):

From @Rayon comment.

You can use `oninput` or [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) events to check on typing.

```js
let degreeInput = document.getElementById('Degree');
degreeInput.oninput = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value < 73) {
    alert(" your degree is less than required ");
  }
};
```

But.. this JavaScript will be work on **every** keyboard input. Let's add [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849221/ajax-delay-for-search-on-typing-in-form-field) for it.

```js
let degreeInput = document.getElementById('Degree');
let delayTimer;

degreeInput.oninput = (e) => {
  clearTimeout(delayTimer);
  delayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (e.target.value < 73) {
      alert(" your degree is less than required ");
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

This will be add delay once keyboard input and wait for 1000 (1 second). If there is no any keyboard input between this the function will be work.

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/26cpLou1/).

Comment: Thank you it’s help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that all of your code? If so, the function isn't being called. Someone in the comments suggested an input function, but that wouldn't work if you want the number to potentially be multiple digits. Here are two possibilities:

1. This would call every time you press enter ("submitting" the form):

html:

```html
<form onsubmit="jsdegree(event)">
  <input id="Degree" name="degree" type="number">
</form>
```

You could also add, between the first `<input>` and the closing `</form>` tag, a submit button: `<input type-"submit">` and then people could also trigger the event by pressing it.

JavaScript:

```js
function jsdegree(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var deg = document.getElementById('Degree').value;
  if (deg <73 ) {
    alert(" your degree is less than required ");
  }
}
```

Note the `event.preventDefault()` is important here, otherwise pressing enter will reload the page.

2. This would call every time you click away from the input:

html:

```html
<input id="Degree" name="degree" type="number" onchange="jsdegree()">
```

And your JavaScript could stay the same.

Comment: No it’s not all the cod just part I struggle with :( , it didn’t submit if the degree is more than73 what’s the wrong?

Comment: @OWLMajedah are you adding an event listener to the input? If not, that's what's wrong